# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener for Flutter

Tags: flutter

In Android, you can do the following to listen to shared preference change

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
                           SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        // your stuff here
    }
};
```

Is it possible to do this using flutter? I have read through the official flutter [shared_preference](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-) and this features seems not yet implemented.

Is there any other library or ways to achieve the above without diving into native code. Thanks.

Comment: I took a look at some other plugins and it seems like none of them provide this feature. I would suggest opening an issue and, if it's not effective, studying related topics and making a PR is the best chance you got.

Comment: Can you share the situation where you need that listener?

Comment: `making a PR is the best chance you got` Yup, I think I need to make an PR.

Comment: `Can you share the situation where you need that listener?` I have made an Notification inside Android / iOS that would update the user GPS and save it to Shared Preference. I would like to read the updated GPS location that is inside the Shared Preference inside Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around, add the following codes to your main():

```
void funTimerMain() async  {
  // here check any changes to SharedPreferences, sqflite, Global Variables  etc...
  if (bolAnythingChanged) {
    // do something

    // 'refresh' any page you want (below line using Redux as example)
    GlobalVariables.storeHome.dispatch(Actions.Increment);
  }

 // recall this timer every x milliseconds
 new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () async { 
  funTimerMain(); 
  }); 

}

// call the timer for the first time
funTimerMain();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this for sure will work, but this will be terrible efficiency though......

Comment: I'm using this technique to watch any 'external events' NOT happenning inside the app.  And actually, I have another 'if' inside the timer to check 'some' events every x seconds instead of 1 second, and this x is different for each different event, for example, check SharedPreferences every 5 seconds, check sqflite every minute, using x(s) the efficiency is not quite bad in actual situation.  And this funTimerMain continues to run even the app is in background, but it is stopped when the app is killed.  To conclude, the loop runs every 1 second, But the checking runs every x seconds.

Comment: Alright, let me see if I can implement that, and check the performance.
If performance ok then I will accept this answer, thanks.

Comment: As I am too lazy to make the PR to flutter for now, this is the best solution available to use if developer need to get SharedPreferences. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily "listen" to SharedPreferences using a package like [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod).

### Initialize sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}
```

### Create the stateProvider

```
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

final keepOnTopProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) {
  return sharedPreferences?.getBool('on_top') ?? true;
});
```

### Update your UI when something changes

```
class SettingsView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SettingsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    bool onTop = ref.watch(keepOnTopProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Settings'), centerTitle: false),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        children: [
          SwitchListTile(
            title: const Text('Keep on top'),
            value: onTop,
            onChanged: (value) async {
              sharedPreferences?.setBool('on_top', value);
              ref.read(keepOnTopProvider.notifier).state = value;
              await windowManager.setAlwaysOnTop(value);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This looks very promising and much more elegant. When I have time and tested it out will accept your answer :)